# Address Book - Select email of Linked contact

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook, peoplepicker

I am trying to fetch selected email property in delegate callback mentioned below

```
-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {
        if (property==kABPersonEmailProperty) {
            ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
            if (ABMultiValueGetCount(emails) > 0) {
                NSString *email = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)
                ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(emails,identifier));
                [recipientEmail setText:email];
                [peoplePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            }
             CFRelease(emails);
        }
        return NO;
    }
```

But If I select the email property of linked contact (Having single email) I get the identifier as 0, as a result I get the first email-id of primary contact. 
    Eg: John - john@gmail.com
               john26@gmail.com
        Roger (Linked Contact) - roger@gmail.com

When I select roger@gmail.com I get john@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this same issue. I get the wrong email when I select accounts with multiple email addresses. When I loop through the selected ABMutableMultiValueRef...

```
for (CFIndex ix = 0; ix < ABMultiValueGetCount(emails); ix++) {
   CFStringRef label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emails, ix);
   CFStringRef value = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, ix);
   NSLog(@"I have a %@ address: %@", label, value);
   if (label) CFRelease(label);
   if (value) CFRelease(value);
}
```

... I get multiple occurrences of the same address, but some with null labels.

```
> I have a (null) address: john@home.com
> I have a _$!<Work>!$_ address: jsmith@work.com
> I have a _$!<Home>!$_ address: john@home.com
```

The workaround I will try is to filter out the null labels first, see if the ABMultiValueIdentifier 'fits', and if not revert to the null labels. Unless you have found something?

Edit: this works for me.

```
    NSMutableArray *labeled = [NSMutableArray new];
    ABMutableMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    for (CFIndex ix = 0; ix < ABMultiValueGetCount(emails); ix++) {
        CFStringRef label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emails, ix);
        CFStringRef value = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, ix);
        if (label != NULL) {
            [labeled addObject:(NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(value)];
        }
        if (label) CFRelease(label);
        if (value) CFRelease(value);
    }
    NSString *email;
    if (labeled.count > identifier) {
        email = [labeled objectAtIndex:identifier];
    } else {
        CFStringRef emailRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, identifier);
        email = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(emailRef);
    }
```